# NodeJS Pass parameter to mysql query

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am building nodeJS application .I want to pass parameter to my query statement .Below is the module that processes what I am looking for  but unfortenately the insertion succeeds whithout the value of my parameter I passed to my query.when I check it to my database new row is inserted but with values of null.

**Below is my database table capture for this app**

[image]

```
app.post('/login',function(req, res){
var name = req.session.name ;
var pass = req.session.pass;
var mail = req.session.mail ;

con.connect(function(err){
   con.query("INSERT INTO register values(null, ?, ?, ?)",[name,mail,pass],
            function(err,result){
                if(err) { return console.log("Error when registration");}
                console.log("registration succeeded + query");

             }); 
       });
});
```

thanks in advance

**NOTE : No issue with database connection**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use req.bosy instead os req.session. For that you need to require body-parser and configure it like

```
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
}));
```

and in your code, you have to replace req.session.name with req.params.name like that. Please try this. Hope this helps. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @ Bimal Kunar it works now.I have forgotten that body parser was the one that make that job , thanks

Comment: Please dont forget to give an upvote if it really helped you. Please accept this answer too. Thanks

Comment: @ Bimal Kunar UNFORTENATELY my reputation dont allow me to upvote good answer , But I promise you that as soon as my reputation enable me I will

Answer (score 1):

Request object does not have `session` property. I think you may be looking for `body` property.

Comment: Thanks @ kubawal  it works now.I have forgotten that body parser was the one that make that job , thanks

Answer (score -4):

```js
app.post('/login',function(req, res){
    //params
    const name = req.body.name ;
    const pass = req.body.pass;
    const mail = req.body.mail ;
    // sql syntax
    const syntaxSQL = "INSERT INTO register (name,pass,mail) values ('"+name+"','"+pass+"','"+mail+"')" ;

    con.connect(function(err){
       con.query(syntaxSQL, // <== use your previously built query here
                function(err,result){
                    if(err) { return console.log("Error when registration");}
                    console.log("registration succeeded + query");

                 }); 
           });
    });
```

Comment: This is SQL injection friendly code. Please escape values or use parametric queries.